# Dynamodb Query condition missed key schema element: provinceId

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, serverless

Here is my dynamodb table, it contains both partition & sort key, can I fetch data based on country only?

```
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: 'provinceId'
            AttributeType: 'S'
          - AttributeName: 'countryId'
            AttributeType: 'S'
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        TableName: 'province-country-list'
        PointInTimeRecoverySpecification:
          PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: true
        Tags:
          - Key: 'STAGE'
            Value: '${self:provider.stage}'
          - Key: 'CostCenter'
            Value: !Sub '${self:provider.stage}-${AWS::AccountId}'
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: 'provinceId'
            KeyType: 'HASH'
          - AttributeName: 'countryId'
            KeyType: 'RANGE'
        # ProvisionedThroughput:
        #     ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        #     WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

this is what i tried

```
const params = {
      TableName: 'province-country-list',
      KeyConditionExpression: 'countryId = :countryId',
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':countryId': countryId,
      },
    };
    const provincesList = await dynamoDb.query(params).promise();
```

getting
Query condition missed key schema element: provinceId

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot search on `countryId` only as its your sort key, you can search with `provinceId` though, as that is your partition key.

> You must provide the name of the partition key attribute and a single value for that attribute. Query returns all items with that partition key value. Optionally, you can provide a sort key attribute and use a comparison operator to refine the search results.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

To be able to search with `countryId` consider creating a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html)